# Alerts not firing on window load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-events

I have tried in Firefox, IE, and Chrome, and with the following code, none of my alerts fire.  Either on pageload or when I click on an image.  I am extremely new to JavaScript, but really appreciate the power it has regarding user experience.  I would really like to learn it better, and hopefully, one of you folks would be able to help me understand why this won't work...  I will include the full HTML as I have heard that JScript can be quite finicky when coming to selectors and DOM objects.  I also have no idea how to properly throw errors in JavaScript... :(

```
<html> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function preview(img, selection) { 
alert("firedTwo");

} 

$(document).ready(function () { 
alert("firedThree");
}); 

$(window).load(function () { 
alert("fired");
});

</script>

<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/profile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" >
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png" >


<title>CityGuru.ca - Saskatoon: Profile Editor</title>

</head> 

<body>
                         
<h1>Profile Picture Upload</h1>

<div id="subHeader">Upload Picture</div>
<div id="subContainer">
        <h2>Create Thumbnail</h2>
        <div align="center">
            <img src="../images/users/saskatoon/1/photo.jpg" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" id="thumbnail" alt="Create Thumbnail" />
            <div style="border:1px #e5e5e5 solid; float:left; position:relative; overflow:hidden; width:60px; height:60px;">
                <img src="../images/users/saskatoon/1/photo.jpg" style="position: relative;" alt="Thumbnail Preview" />
            </div>
            <br style="clear:both;"/>
            <form name="thumbnail" action="http://saskatoon.CityGuru.ca/includes/profileEditor.php?action=picUpload" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="x1" value="" id="x1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="y1" value="" id="y1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="x2" value="" id="x2" />
                <input type="hidden" name="y2" value="" id="y2" />
                <input type="hidden" name="w" value="" id="w" />
                <input type="hidden" name="h" value="" id="h" />
                <input type="submit" name="upload_thumbnail" value="Save Thumbnail" id="save_thumb" />
            </form>
        </div>
    <hr />
        <h2>Upload Photo</h2>
    <form name="photo" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://saskatoon.CityGuru.ca/includes/profileEditor.php?action=picUpload" method="post">
    Photo <input type="file" name="image" size="30" /> <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
    </form>
</div>   
                               


</body>
</html>
```

***NOTE***
When using FireFox's web console, the only JS error I get is:

> $ is not defined

Comment: that only error tells you a lot...

Comment: You are using jQuery but never include it. Also as the others said, your `script` belongs in the `head` of the page. I recommend to read some introductory tutorial for JavaScript and jQuery before you continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$() syntax is jQuery, not native javascript. (though some other libraries use this same syntax as well). You need to include jQuery for this to work.

Comment: Ahh, will do, just so strange, I just reread the tutorial I built this from and there is no reference to jQuery in the examples and theirs works.  I will definitely try that out now!  thanks!

Comment: @MaurerPower: Which tutorial? Could you provide a link?

Comment: It was a photo uploader I was tinkering with overnight goodness I can't remember which one.  I will try and find it again and repost.  And the jQuery call was eXACTLY what I was looking for!  Thank you so much!  Also, because I am learning javascript, I really appreciate you pointing out the syntax issue, I thought it was just a native javascript thing.  Almost all the things I read assume jQuery or other sort of library I guess.  Thanks again for helping and in such a positive way!

Answer (score 1):

add this http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js in script tag in head section  there is no jquery in your above code so $(document.ready(function() dont work

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html> 

<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function preview(img, selection) { 
 alert("firedTwo");

} 
...

</head>
```

The important things to notice:

1. You don't have jQuery referenced: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
2. You sorta put things out of order...

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it was extremely clear and very helpful.  I had already accepted nymous' answer, and yours was extremely helpful also! UPVOTE!

Comment: Too bad you can't accept both :P but glad you got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, scripts like this usually go in the head.

Second, you shouldn't put JavaScript before the doctype ever.

Third, I don't see your opening head tag, just the closing tag.

Finally, you need to include a jquery script somewhere in the head.

Comment: JQuery scripts are required for this usage?  Please see edits for the tagging issues I have addressed following your advice.

Comment: The $ functions you used are normally indicative of using jquery. Either get rid of the document ready and window load functions, or include jquery.

Comment: @MaurerPower: jQuery is not required at all. But **you** make use of it, so you should be aware of what it is. Don't use it, if you don't understand it. Take the time to learn...

Comment: @FelixKling It isn't a production thing.  I am trying to learn it, that's why I am trying, and when I was discouraged enough to give up on it, I came to experts to see if they could make it clear to me, which they did.  And I am extremely grateful for that.  I will retag as homework so it's more clear.  Thanks for your time.